# Matching come and go to location data

Tags: r, data.table

I have data on movement, from and to, and would like to say something about a location, for example, how many things come and go from location 1.

```
test = data.table(day = c(1,1,1), from = c(1,2,1), to =c(3,1,3))
test[ , `:=`( total_from = .N) , by = c("day", "from") ]
test[ , `:=`( total_to = .N) , by = c("day", "to") ]


   day from to total_from total_to
1:   1    1  3          2        2
2:   1    2  1          1        1
3:   1    1  3          2        2
```

I can not simply add both total columns as they do not related to the same location. 
My preferable outcome would be:

```
   day location count
1:   1        1     3
2:   1        2     1
3:   1        3     2
```

I don't know what to search for, as I am quite certain R has some function for this, so maybe if someone could send me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

Comment: do an example that does not only consist of `1,2,3` numbers

Comment: `melt(test, id = 1, value.name = "location")[, .N, by = .(day, location)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is *graph data*. Each location is called either a *vertex* or a *node* (they are interchangeable), and the quantity you are trying to compute is called the *degree* of a node. The "in degree" is the total amount flowing in, and the "out degree" is the total amount flowing out; the "degree" overall is the sum of the two.

There are two solutions possible:

1. Compute in-degree and out-degree by reshaping your data and summing,  as in the comment by Jaap
2. Use a graph library to construct the graph and compute degree efficiently.

I'll demonstrate both.

## Reshaping

The first solution uses the "reshape" functionality from `data.table`, since you're already using that package:

```
test <- data.table(
    day = c(1,1,1),
    from = c(1,2,1),
    to = c(3,1,3)
)
```

Your data is currently in "wide" format: two of your columns are variations of each other, the amount that flows in or out of the node on a given day.

```
test_long <- melt(test, id.vars = "day", variable.name = "direction", value.name = "location")
```

`melt` reshapes this data into "long" format: you have one column indicating the location, and another indicating the direction. Now you are free to obtain your answer by simply grouping on day and location and computing the number of instances of each group:

```
test_totals <- test_long[, .N, by = .(day, location)]
```

## Graph analysis

Fortunately, `data.table` is very efficient for "groupby" operations.

However, graph data structures are generally more flexible and efficient. [igraph](http://igraph.org/r/) is a powerful and easy-to-use graph analysis package, backed by a well-built C library.

```
library(igraph)


test <- data.table(
    day = c(1,1,1),
    from = c(1,2,1),
    to = c(3,1,3)
)

# the first 2 columns must be the vertices; each row is an edge
# other columns are treated as edge attributes
g <- graph.data.frame(test[, .(from, to, day)]

# returns a named vector of degree for each node
totals <- degree(g)
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional information provided on the graph analysis.

Comment: Question, what if something stays at the samen location and thus you don't want to count it as there has been no movement. for example  on day 1 there is a "movement" from 4, to 4.

Comment: @Hjalmar in `data.table`, you can filter on rows where `from != to` before `melt`ing. In `igraph` I think if you write `degree(g, loops=FALSE)` it will be excluded (but you will have to double-check).